# How to transition multiple background images on a div element?

Tags: jquery, css, background-image, transition

I started with this Codepen example: https://codepen.io/dudleystorey/pen/qEoKzZ

**The JS:**

```
var bgImageArray = ["lonely.jpg", "uluwatu.jpg"..."],
base = "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/full-",
secs = 4;
bgImageArray.forEach(function(img){
    new Image().src = base + img; 
    // caches images, avoiding white flash between background replacements
});

function backgroundSequence() {
    window.clearTimeout();
    var k = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < bgImageArray.length; i++) {
        setTimeout(function(){ 
            document.documentElement.style.background = 
            "url(" + base + bgImageArray[k] + ") no-repeat center center fixed";
            document.documentElement.style.backgroundSize ="cover";
        if ((k + 1) === bgImageArray.length) { setTimeout(function() 
            { backgroundSequence() }, (secs * 1000))} else { k++; }         
        }, (secs * 1000) * i)   
    }
}
backgroundSequence();
```

A fiddle of what I'm trying here: https://jsfiddle.net/ByteMyPixel/x37fk6js/1/

**The JS:**

```
    var bgImageArray = ['~text?txtsize=69&txt=Slide+2&w=816&h=300&txttrack=0', 
            '~text?txtsize=69&txt=Slide+3&w=816&h=300&txttrack=0'],
    base = "https://placeholdit.imgix.net/",
    secs = 4;
    bgImageArray.forEach(function(img){
        new Image().src = base + img; 
        // caches images, avoiding white flash between background replacements
    });

    function backgroundSequence() {
        window.clearTimeout();
        var k = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < bgImageArray.length; i++) {
            setTimeout(function(){ 
                $('.tab-content-wrapper').css('backgroundImage', 
            "url(" + base + bgImageArray[k] + ") no-repeat center center fixed");
                $('.tab-content-wrapper').css('backgroundSize' , "cover");
            if ((k + 1) === bgImageArray.length) { setTimeout(function() 
            { backgroundSequence() }, (secs * 1000))} else { k++; }         
            }, (secs * 1000) * i)   
        }
    }
    backgroundSequence();
```

Basically I want the background image on the right of this section to transition between about 5 different images:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've updated your fiddle with a working version: https://jsfiddle.net/sm1215/r5or5w6m/3/

A couple things that were off

1. Your external resource was incorrectly pulling in jQuery-ui instead of just jQuery. If you check your console, you can see there is a problem with jQuery being undefined. This is the first thing to check to make sure the proper resource is being loaded.
2. This line below is slightly off.

   $('.tab-content-wrapper').css('backgroundImage', "url(" + base + bgImageArray[k] + ") no-repeat center center fixed");

You're setting too many properties at once for "backgroundImage". The properties "no-repeat center center fixed" are multiple properties that defined "background-repeat, background-position, and background-attachment" respectively. You could set all of these at once by just using 'background' (this is considered shorthand css), or you can set each one individually by wrapping your css in curly braces like so:

```
$('.tab-content-wrapper').css({
    'backgroundImage': "url(" + base + bgImageArray[k] + ")",
    'background-repeat': "no-repeat",
    'background-position': "center center",
    'background-attachment': fixed"
});
```

It's also unnecessary to set all of these for every new image based on your current fiddle's CSS. These are already set once there, so no need to do it all again. You only need to change the URL.

3. Careful with your jQuery selectors. There are too many periods on this line and it will cause problems

   $('..tab-content-wrapper').css('backgroundSize' , "cover");

Comment: Awesome, thank you.  Yeah I realized after I posted this that I had the wrong cdn url in there for jQuery etc...  I like your cleaner js version without all of the background properties too, so thank you much!

Comment: hah yeah i didn't even notice at first, until i couldn't figure out why jquery kept showing up undefined, and thank you!

Comment: Your solution is perfect, but do you also have a solution to add another array that contains URLs to match each single image, or an object with image address and URL matched to make the div clickable?

Answer (score 1):

Replace `backgroundImage` with `background` in your `backgroundSequence()` function like this :

```
function backgroundSequence() {
    window.clearTimeout();
    var k = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < bgImageArray.length; i++) {
        setTimeout(function(){ 
            $('.tab-content-wrapper').css('background', "url(" + base + bgImageArray[k] + ") no-repeat center center fixed");
            $('.tab-content-wrapper').css('backgroundSize' , "cover");
        if ((k + 1) === bgImageArray.length) { setTimeout(function() { backgroundSequence() }, (secs * 1000))} else { k++; }         
        }, (secs * 1000) * i)   
    }
}
```

[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fos5hcp3/)

Answer (score 0):

This is what you are going to want. Use setInterval() instead of setTimeout() for this type of thing:

```
var bgImageArray = ['~text?txtsize=69&txt=Slide+1&w=816&h=300&txttrack=0',
  '~text?txtsize=69&txt=Slide+2&w=816&h=300&txttrack=0', 
  '~text?txtsize=69&txt=Slide+3&w=816&h=300&txttrack=0'],
    base = "https://placeholdit.imgix.net/",
    secs = 4;
  var index = 1;
    bgImageArray.forEach(function(img){
        new Image().src = base + img; 
        // caches images, avoiding white flash between background replacements
    });
  var intialUrl = "url(" + base + bgImageArray[0] + ")";
  $('.tab-content-wrapper').css('background-image', intialUrl);
  var interval = setInterval(function () {
    var url = "url(" + base + bgImageArray[index%3] + ") no-repeat center center";
    $('.tab-content-wrapper').css({'background': url, 'background-size': 'cover'});
    index++;
  }, 5000);
```